# Windows 10 boots too slow during session init

Tags: windows-10, boot

It takes about 10 mins to boot Windows 10. I have used the WPA, and the result shows `Microsoft-Windows-StorPort/TaskRequestTimerCall/OpCodeRequestTimerCall` takes a lot of time during `Session init`.

[image: image of windows performance analysis]

How can I fix this?

Comment: share the ETL file, the picture is not helpful, becasue you haven't applied the profile as I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found your answer, but I've been struggling with the same issue for about 2 weeks now.  (Timing indicates it may have had ties to the Win 1709 patch?)  Like you, my WPA showed init was around 9-10 min, over 95% of which was idle.

After trying to play with FastBoot settings, digging around Boot Recordings before and after multiple **sfc /scannow** and **DISM.exe**  attempts, trying to repair windows from USB boot, updating every conceivable driver (apparently video drivers have historically caused delays with the init phase?) -- I got my boot time back to normal immediately after *disabling hibernation mode via cmd prompt*!  My hiberfil.sys was almost 13g, and it seems that trying to read this (from an SSD) was causing the massive delays.

(Link to powercfg commands -
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx)

From cmd prompt with admin privileges --- "**powercfg.exe -h off**"

**NOTE -**  This will delete your hiberfil.sys file, so back that up if you want to be safe!

I have not tried to re-enable hibernation yet, but hopefully this helps you with your delays in the meantime!

-SLightfoot

Comment: Re-enabled hibernation a couple days later, still a booting quickly despite my hiberfil now being over 16g.  So, not certain what in that original file was causing the hangups.

Comment: thanks a lot. I disabled hybernation and my boot time got reduced from 6 min to 10 seconds.

Comment: "Computer repair technicians hate them, remove 60 seconds to 20 minutes from your boot time with this simple trick", but seriously this works. I had 70 extra seconds on my Session Init, googled for months, tried everything, only this worked. I don't think it is related to disk activity as I have a fast nvme and couldn't find any record of it with WPA, most likely a windows bug.

Comment: For me it does not change situation.